# Is there established terminology for a "star generated by a point and set"?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, plane-geometry

Let $[A;B]$ denote the line segment between points $A$ and $B$ in a plane.

A [star-domain, or radially convex set](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_domain) is a set $X$ in which there is a point $x$ such that $[x;B]\subseteq X$ for every $B\in X$.

Given a point $x$ and a set $S$ of other points, I would like to use existing terminology, if it exists, to describe the following union:

$\bigcup\{[x;s]\mid s\in S\}$

The link above is the most relevant hit I found. I was expecting to possibly find something like "the star generated by $x$ and $S$" or "the radially convex hull from $x$ to $S$."

Thanks for any references.

Comment: The cone on $S$ with vertex $x$ is one I've heard.

Comment: @PaulSinclair hm, that's an interesting one, but it's not very well suited to my use-case. You're reminding me of an important restriction I should add.

Comment: If you do not like the "cone" name (I also saw that one used), you just have to invent your own: I do not believe there is anything better in the literature. You can also use the name "quasiconvex hull of two sets", but some people will be confused by it. (Quasiconvex hull of $\{A, B\}$ is the union of all segments connecting points of A and B.)

Comment: @MoisheCohen "cone" would be a great choice  if $S$ was a connected subset of a hyperplane and $x$ was a point not on the hyperplane, but it  isn't very apt for coplanar sets, where the even the "star" terminology is more attractive.  If it turns out nobody has seen an established term I would pick some variant of "radially convex hull" or "star generated by"